# find - What happens if you omit -name and single quotes?

Tags: linux, terminal, find

Instead of typing
`find / -name 'filename'`
I accidentally typed
`find / filename`

(note the missing `-name` and single quotes).

The command printed the whole root file tree (it was a very long list) and appended `find: „filename“: No such file or directory` at the end of it. What did it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
find / filename
```

`find` assumes you want to search two directories/files named `/` and `filename`. `/` is present, so it lists all files in it and `filename` is not there in your current directory, so it errors out.

It's functionally equivalent to running `find` twice:

`find /` and `find filename`

Create a file/directory named `filename` in your current working directory, you'll understand its behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`find` interpreted both `/` and `filename` as starting points, with no expression:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>    find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-D debugopts] [-Olevel] [starting-point...] [expression]
> ```